# Aggregate Functions in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, aggregate-functions

If I have a table containing a column of text and a column of integers, how can I sum the integers specific to each text entry? Example:

```
text1 | 4
text2 | 2
text3 | 5
text2 | 3
text1 | 2
```

I want to do:
SELECT Text,SUM(Number)
FROM TABLE

However, that sums all the numbers together (text1 | 16). How can I sum the numbers with each text entry independently?(
    text1 | 6
    text2 | 5
    text3 | 5 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the `GROUP BY` clause: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#resultset

Example usage:

```
SELECT   mycolumn, SUM(myothercolumn) 
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY mycolumn
ORDER BY mycolumn;
```

Comment: I think I had done GROUP BY on "myothercolumn" and ORDER BY separately, but never though to combine them. You're exactly right in the example you gave back. Thank you kindly :)